# Read text files in spark java with fixed width as well as delimiters

Tags: java, apache-spark

I need to read a text file in spark which has first few columns as fixed width and remaining columns delimited by '^'. How can i read the files with both fixed width and '^' delimiters together?

Comment: You can create a dataframe by reading the file and then split it in two dataframes using substring(as you said half of it is fixed width so it must be having an end index) and then process it like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57428503/how-we-can-parse-logs-in-spark-using-dataframe/57429523#57429523

Comment: if you need a detailed answer, please provide the snippet of the source file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way using the csv reader build into the dataframes API. You will need to read it in as RDD and split into columns using custom logic. The code snippet below show how you can proceed with it.

```
val data = sc.textFile("filename.csv").map(line => <...custom logic to be applied on each row...>)

import spark.implicits._
data.toDF()
```